# System.Data.SQLite running under Xamarin on IOS

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, system.data.sqlite

I have C# code base that runs under Windows and uses System.Data.SQLite. All assemblies are .netstandard2.0 and it should run under Xamarin IOS, but System.Data.SQLite depends on native code dll file and there is no build for native SQLite.Interop.dll for IOS.

Is it possible to build the sqlite native code from source for IOS. Is it going to work with DLLImports that managed code uses under IOS?

Comment: You could use `SQLite.NET` instead. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/data/using-sqlite-orm

Comment: I know I can rewrite my code base and use other implementation. My questions is how to do it without modification of the code base

Comment: As i know, `System.Data.SQLite` do not support Xamarin. You could use the `System.Data` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/data-cloud/system.data instead or `SQLite.NET`.